# Bind <rich:listShuttle> or put two list in render attribute

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

What do I do if I have to put two rendered condition on listshuttle.

I have a `<rich:listshuttle>` and I have put `rendered="#{!empty Bean.arrayList}".`

So if arraylist is empty this component is not rendered.
However on certain occassion I want to render this component even when the arraylist is not empty.

It may be possible to bind `<rich:listShuttle>` with the backing bean but how can it be achieved.

Also is it possible if I put two list in the rendered field.But I think my objective still won't be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to put any EL expression evaluating to boolean in rendered

```
rendered="#{(not empty Bean.arrayList) or (empty Bean.arrayList and Bean.conditionMet)}"
```

Comment: I need to try whether I can use or in the EL expression...Also I explored and found I can bind listshuttle with HtmlListShuttle attribute in the backing bean which gives me full control of the component.